# Text on node getting overlapped after zoom out on d3 tree layout on edge browser of windows 10

Tags: d3.js

I have created tree using D3.js. Name, version number getting overlapped after zoom out on

d3 v4 tree layout on edge browser of windows 10
again text disappeared while zooming at certail level of zoom in same graph.
Code is in given jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oo66o0q0/8/

Comment: Anyone have solution to this issue?